# Laravel auth with custom guard doens't work

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, guard

I'm trying to do custom admin authentication with username. I couldn't catch the error where would I to focus.
[image: this is my custom admin guard]

[image: provider]

[image: admin table]

[image: admin model]

My login class below. Auth::guard('admin') attempt doesn't work. Pages and other crud process works well. When I post the login form it just return back
[image: AdminController page]

[image: routers]